# JavaScript scoping not assign variable

Tags: javascript, scoping

I'm writing a function in JS, but I have a problem with the variabile **marker**.

The code:

```
    function piano(numero, link) {

            var marker;
            this.marker = marker;

            var immagine = loadImage(link, marker);
            this.immagine = immagine


            function createMarker() {

                    return new RichMarker({

                           ....

                    });
            }

            function loadImage(link, marker) {

                    var immagine = new Image();

                    immagine.src = link;

                    immagine.onload = function() {
                            marker = createMarker();  
                    };  

                    return immagine;
             }

             ....
```

The variabile **immagine** is initialized calling the function **loadImage** for the loading of the picture.

In this function it's the code:

```
                    immagine.onload = function() {
                            marker = createMarker();  
                    };
```

which have to do the assignment of **marker** after the loading of the image.

When I try to access to **marker**, after the loading of the image, it always result *undefined*; and I know for sure that the *RichMarker* has been created.

I don't understand why it's happening this.

Comment: JavaScript variables will store a reference to an object, but you can't share a reference to say a `Number` or `String` or `undefined`. If marker is anything but an array or object, then `marker` and `this.marker` will not be the same object when you modify it later (which it is undefined, so what you are doing will not work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript variables will store a reference to an object, but you can't share a reference to say a `Number` or `String` or `undefined`. If `marker` is anything but an array or object, then `marker` and `this.marker` will not be the same object when you modify it later (think of it as copying the value, instead of assigning the reference).

Instead try scoping the `this` object, so later you can reference that *object* again:

```
function piano(numero, link) {
    var self = this;
    this.immagine = loadImage(link);


    function createMarker() {
        return new RichMarker({
            //...
        });
    }

    function loadImage(link) {
        var immagine = new Image();
        immagine.src = link;

        immagine.onload = function() {
            //use the scoped version of 'this'
            self.marker = createMarker();  
        };  

        return immagine;
     }

     //...
 }
```